# SocketException while running Solr Query with lots of filtering

Tags: exception, solr, connection, abort

I'm trying to run a query to my local solr server (single instance). 
I'm also adding filters for ids.
So in case of 10000 ids I create 10 Filter Queries, each of which consists of 1000 ids.

Filter Query looks like this:

```
"id:(1 2 3 n)"
```

I'm also using Solrj so it goes like:

```
query.addFilterQuery("id:(1 2 3 n)");
```

But after some threshold (it was 1000 5 minutes ago and now it's around 800) I'm starting to receive exceptions:

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: No live SolrServers available to handle this request
    Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://localhost:8080/solr
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:416)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:181)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBHttpSolrServer.request(LBHttpSolrServer.java:447)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

I googled around but found only about maxBoolean queries which is not my case probably

Comment: I found a solution. Turns out that by default Solrj uses GET instead of POST. The simple way to fix is to use server.query(query, SolrRequest.METHOD.POST).

Answer (score 0):

Yes Igor,
You are correct.

By default Solrj uses GET instead of POST. 
So you have to use server.query(query, SolrRequest.METHOD.POST).